# Múltiple tablas con las mismas columnas ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tengo una base de datos existente y tengo que usar unas 30 tablas que tienen en común las mismas columnas.

### Tabla01

Campo 1 |
Campo 2

### Tabla02

Campo 1 |
Campo 2

### Tabla0X

Campo 1 |
Campo 2

Estoy usando **EF CORE 2**
y lo que realice hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

Cree un objeto común

```
public class Custom
{
    public string Campo1 { get; set; }
    public string Campo2 { get; set; }
}
```

Por cada entidad (clase) mapeo por reflection cada propiedad con su valor de esta clase custom

```
    public static object CopyCustomToEntity(this Type entity, Custom custom)
    {
        var typeOfCustom = custom.GetType();
        var typeOfEntity = entity;

        var entityType = Activator.CreateInstance(entity);

        // copy properties
        foreach (var propertyOfCustom in typeOfCustom.GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyOfEntity = typeOfEntity.GetProperty(propertyOfCustom.Name);
            propertyOfEntity.SetValue(entityType, propertyOfCustom.GetValue(custom));
        }

        return entityType;
    }
```

y hago el insert (xej) pasando el tipo **object**

```
    public void Create(object entity)
    {
        _context.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Funciona correctamente, pero me encuentro ahora con el problema de obtener un registro por id u obtener todos los registros de una tabla en particular.

Sé que con reflection lo puedo seguir logrando, pero antes de continuar quisiera saber si existe un patrón u otra practica que pueda llegar aplicar mejor para este caso.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Por qué no usar herencia:

```
public class Custom
{
    public string Campo1 { get; set; }
    public string Campo2 { get; set; }
}

public class Hija1 : Custom {}
public class Hija2 : Custom {}
```

Para persistir los datos, ya no tienes que trabajar con object:

```
public void Create(Base entity)
{
    _context.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Si necesitas obtener un resgistro por Id, pero de una clase en particular, quizá mejor usando generics:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : Base
{
    public int Create(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return entity.Id;
    }
}
```

Aquí puedes obtener más información sobre el [patrón Repository](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/bc97ba79-7493-46c3-9ea1-7b8ac5e29e60/patrn-repository?forum=vcses)